# Need an Applescript to go to a specific slide number in PowerPoint

Tags: applescript, powerpoint

I need a simple AppleScript that will cause PowerPoint to move to a specified slide number.  I unfortunately am not familiar enough with AppleScript to properly interpret the information in the Applescript Library for PowerPoint.  I think if someone can get me started I can take it from there.

The script just needs to reference the active presentation. If I could speak to my computer I just need to tell it to "go to slide #5" or "go to slide #2", etc.

The script needs to work while in Slideshow mode as the presentation will be running on a separate screen.   Thanks so much for the help, I haven't been able to find this anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
my gotoSlide(2)
```

```
on gotoSlide(whichSlide)
    -- whichSlide is the integer position of the slide
    tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
        activate
        tell active presentation
            set theView to view of document window 1
            go to slide theView number whichSlide
        end tell
    end tell
end gotoSlide
```

Comment: This does not work while there's an active slideShow.  A 'view' of the 'document window' is the main editing view and as long as the view type is 'normal type' the 'go to slide' command will change the selection to that slide but not the slideshow.  'go to slide' does not appear to work on the slideshowView, only on the 'normal type' document view.